# How don't autostart all programs, that was opened before shut down

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, autostart

When I login, all programs that was not closed, before I turn off the computer, starts.

How can I don't start them, but start some list of programmes? (No matter, was they opened or not)

Comment: Choose not to save the session when you log out.

Comment: @UriHerrera, and how to do it was the answer. Now solution found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System Settings` > `System administration` > `Startup and shutdown` > `Session management` > `On login: start with empty session`